# Adobe Flash Professional CC - HTML5 Canvas - Main Timeline

Tags: javascript, html, flash, canvas

When entering in the following code via a layer in the main timeline the gotoAndPlay does not work, and all the labels are correct.

```
this.moveRight.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    alert("called");

    //gotoAndPlay("lblSlide2"); // Output - ReferenceError: gotoAndPlay is not defined
    //this.gotoAndPlay("lblSlide2"); // Output - Is not a function.
    //MovieClip(parent).this.gotoAndPlay("lblSlide2"); // Output - ReferenceError: MovieClip is not defined
    //MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndPlay("lblSlide2"); // Output - ReferenceError: MovieClip is not defined
});

//this.gotoAndPlay("lblSlide2"); // Works
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Edited previous code to show the output of the javascript debugger.

Answer (score 1):

I found success using the soltion on this question: [Flash HTML5 canvas fl_MouseOverHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717725/flash-html5-canvas-fl-mouseoverhandler)

For your scenario, I believe the application would look like this:

```
this.moveRight.addEventListener("click",moveRightClick.bind(this));


function moveRightClick(){
    this.gotoAndPlay("lblSlide2");
};
```

So don't use an anonymous function, declare it, then add .bind(this) to provide it with a scope.

Comment: Actually, you can bind a scope to an anonymous function:

`this.moveRight.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    this.gotoAndPlay("lblSlide2"); 
}.bind(this));`