# Scale on Hover in AS3

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a symbol that I want to scale using the timeline when it's hovered. I can't figure it out.

```
var frequency = 3;
stage.enableMouseOver(frequency);
this.bitez_main.addEventListener("mouseover", fl_MouseOverHandler_1);

function fl_MouseOverHandler_1()
{
this.bitez_main.bitez_over.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

[image: action on hover]

Comment: Fixed tags because it looks like **JavaScript**, not **ActionScript** at all: https://helpx.adobe.com/animate/kb/as-to-html5.html There's seemingly a similar question which has an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717725/flash-html5-canvas-fl-mouseoverhandler

Comment: thanks. I have seen that question. There it goes to a point in the main timeline. In my question movieclip has its own timeline and I can't get to use gotoAndPlay function there

Answer (score 1):

I have followed up Animate's code wizard and it worked. 
This is the code that's generated

```
var _this = this;
/*
Mousing over the specified symbol instance executes a function.
'3' is the number of the times event should be triggered.
*/
stage.enableMouseOver(3);
_this.main_mc_bitez.on('mouseover', function(){
/*
Moves the playhead to the specified frame number in the timeline and continues playback from that frame.
Can be used on the main timeline or on movie clip timelines.
*/
_this.main_mc_bitez.gotoAndPlay(2);
});
```